# dispatch_group_wait waits forever

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I'm studying how `dispatch_async()` works.

I tried this snippet in `main()`:

```
typedef void(^VoidBlock)();

VoidBlock aBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"do work in main queue");
};
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), aBlock);
```

But the Block is never called. I thought that maybe the main thread ends before the block runs.
Then I tried this:

```
dispatch_group_t aGroup = dispatch_group_create();
VoidBlock aBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"do work in main queue");
    dispatch_group_leave(aGroup);
};
dispatch_group_enter(aGroup);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), aBlock);
dispatch_group_wait(aGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

This doesn't work either (the Block doesn't get called).
The difference is that now the main thread (correctly) blocks on the statement `dispatch_group_wait(aGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`

What's the problem?

Comment: Do you mean you tried this code in `main.m` file?

Comment: Yes, inside `main.m` and inside `main` function of course!

Comment: what did you try with looking at output on console or even with using breakpoints?

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code.

Comment: GCD defines a Block type `dispatch_block_t` that you can use instead of making your own `VoidBlock` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you did not create an iOS Project (or any other project type that triggers an runloop) but a "Command Line Tool". If this is the case:

**Your first approach**

In general your first approach is fine, but `main()` returns (and thus your app finishes running) before your async call is triggerd.

**Your second approach**

You got the right idea in your second approach: Wait until your async job has finished.

Your implementation is causing a deadlock though. `wait` is blocking the thread it is called from (the main thread) until your block has finished running, but the block never runs as the main thread is blocked.

**Solution**

To fix this, dispatch on a different queue than the waiting one:

```
dispatch_group_t aGroup = dispatch_group_create();
VoidBlock aBlock = ^{
      NSLog(@"do work in main queue");
      dispatch_group_leave(aGroup);
};
dispatch_group_enter(aGroup);

 // dispatch on another queue than the one wait will block
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), aBlock);
dispatch_group_wait(aGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

This way the main queue is waiting (blocked) and while your block can be (is) executed on another queue.

---

[@Ishahaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40958528/1457385) to create a "Single View Application" instead of a "Command Line Tool" would also work (as the question was originally taged as "iOS"), even in `main()`. The reason therefore is that iOS applications trigger a runloop (`while(true) { // wait for events }`), so the application still runs after returning from `main()`. See [Apples Runloop Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: I created the project as `Command Line Tool`. Why is this a problem? Similar experiments with other queues (not main) works great!

Comment: You do not have a run loop, so the app finished running after exiting `main()`. Should not work with other queues like `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)` as well.

Comment: no problem with `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)`! The problem is with the main queue. I think because when the main thread go to sleep with `dispatch_group_wait` no blocks can be executed in the main thread anymore....

Comment: Your first approach does not work with DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW is what I meant. I updated the answer to be less mistakable.

Comment: @shallowThought You got some deep thoughts bro. :) Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for iOS, then use "New" "Project" "Single View Application", then put your code into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    typedef void(^VoidBlock)();

    VoidBlock aBlock = ^{
        NSLog(@"do work in main queue");
    };
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), aBlock);
    return YES;
}
```